# Purpose of tuple constructor in python

Tags: python, tuples

I recently came across `tuple()` as a constructor in python, if there exists a difference between just using `()` and `tuple()`, What is it?

Comment: You can pass any sequence as a parameter.

Comment: Nothing, really, just like there is little difference between `list()` and `[]`.

Comment: Same as `[]` vs `list` and `{}` vs `dict`

Comment: `tuple` is the type itself, and like other container types, it can take an iterable as an argument to populate the new instance when called.

Comment: `tuple` is a name for a callable object.

Comment: Probably the only difference is when called with `tuple('abc')`

Comment: Err, to construct a tuple. Is that so surprising?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tuple() vs () for Tuple Comprehension & Tuple Creation](/q/53896896/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really the biggest difference between using the literal constructor of `()` and `tuple()` is the behavior with iterable vs noniterable arguments.

With the literal representation, you can make a tuple like so:

```
>>> (1,2)
(1, 2)
```

You can represent that same tuple without the `()`:

```
>>> 1,2
(1, 2)
```

And a single element tuple, use a trailing comma:

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
>>> 'abc',
('abc',)
```

With the tuple function, the single argument must be iterable, and that can surprise at times:

```
>>> tuple('abc')
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

For a single element tuple element, you would think you can use a trailing comma, but that still may surprise with the function:

```
>>> tuple('abc',)
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

So you have to do:

```
>>> tuple(('abc',))  # or tuple(['abc'])
('abc',)
```

Comment: Ironically it's one less character to pass a list, `tuple(['abc'])` vs `tuple(('abc',))`

Comment: `()` isn't a constructor, literal notation isn't a constructor really

Answer (score 6):

`tuple` is a type.

```
>>> tuple
<class 'tuple'>
```

When you call the type, you can pass any kind of iterable to get back a non-empty tuple containing the elements of the iterable.

```
>>> tuple([1,2,3])
(1, 2, 3)
>>> tuple((1,2,3))
(1, 2, 3)
>>> tuple(i+1 for i in range(3))
(1, 2, 3)
```

If you don't pass an argument, you create an empty tuple.

```
>>> tuple()
()
```

`()` is a literal that evaluates to an empty tuple, just as if you had called the type with no argument.

```
>>> ()
()
>>> tuple() == ()
True
```

Comment: I'll just add here that usually you use `tuple()` when you already have some iterable and you want it as a tuple instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's most useful for converting iterables to tuples. For example say you have a list of lists that you want to convert to a set. Well, lists aren't hashable, but tuples are*, so you can use the constructor to cast them:

```
set(map(tuple, list_of_lists))
```

or

```
set(tuple(x) for x in list_of_lists)
```

* Assuming they contain only hashable elements